# How calculate changing slider values with a maximum value for all?

Tags: javascript

I need to create a slider for a game that you can set skills to each player,

The rules are :

1. Each skill starts at 0.
2. The skills cannot total *more* than 100 points at any time.
3. It should always be possible to assign any 0-100 value to a given skill. Given rule (2), if this gets us over 100 total points, the excess automatically, immediately, removed from the other skills, according to their current values.
4. It's not required to use all 100 points (or any).
5. A skill's value is always an integer.

For example :

- We start with:
  Stamina: 0 | Speed: 0 | Armor: 0 | Strength: 0 | *Remaining: 100*
- The player adds 50 Speed.
  Stamina: 0 | Speed: 50 | Armor: 0 | Strength: 0 | *Remaining: 50*
- The player adds 25 Armor.
  Stamina: 0 | Speed: 50 | Armor: 25 | Strength: 0 | *Remaining: 25*  - 115
- The player now adds 40 Stamina. The excess is automatically reduced from the other skills, weighted by their current values.
  Stamina: 40 | Speed: 40 | Armor: 20 | Strength: 0 | *Remaining: 0*
- The player then reduces Speed to 10.
  Stamina: 40 | Speed: 30 | Armor: 20 | Strength: 0 | *Remaining: 10*
- Finally, the player sets Strength to 100.
  Stamina: 0 | Speed: 0 | Armor: 0 | Strength: 100 | *Remaining: 0*

To do so i've created a function the receives 3 arguments :

1. An array of values of the slider

let arrToCalc = [14,24,55,0]

2. The index number of the skill (0 for Stamina, 1 for Speed ...etc)

let newValueIndex = 2

3. New value for base the calculation on

let newVal = 64.

Im not sure my calculations are accurate so i'm getting partial good results.

when set to

```
    let arrToCalc = [0,50,25,0]
    let newValueIndex = 0
    let newVal = 40
    the results are fine - [40,40,20,0]
```

but when i'm testing it with with other values - it's not always correct.

```js
function calcSkills(currentValues, newValue, newValueIndex) {

  let outArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < currentValues.length; i++) {
    if (i == newValueIndex) {
      currentValues[i] = newValue;
    }
  }

  let calcValues = currentValues.reduce((a, b) => {
    return a + b;
  })

  if (calcValues < 100) {
    outArr = currentValues
    console.log('less', outArr)


  } else {
    let accumulator = 0;
    let isValidVal = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < currentValues.length; i++) {
      let val = currentValues[i];

      if (val && i !== newValueIndex) {
        let temp = 0;
        if (accumulator == 0) {
          isValidVal = (100 - (newValue + val) >= 0 ? true : false);
          if (isValidVal) {
            temp = val - (100 - (newValue + val));

          } else {
            temp = 0;
          }
          accumulator = newValue

        } else {
          accumulator = accumulator + accumulator;
          isValidVal = (100 - accumulator) > 0 ? true : false;
          if (isValidVal) {
            temp = val - (val - (100 - accumulator));
          } else {
            temp = 0;
          }

        }
        outArr.push(temp)

      } else {
        outArr.push(val)
      }

    }


    console.log('greather', outArr)
  }

}

arrToCalc = [44, 55, 25, 0]
newValueIndex = 2
newVal = 40
calcSkills(arrToCalc, newVal, newValueIndex)
```

[image]

Comment: What is the algorithm for the reduction? You want to calculate the ratio of other skills so [10,20,40,0] would have skill 1 reduced by 10%, 2 by 20% and 3 by 40% if one added 50 to the 4th entry?

Comment: Thanks, i'm not sure what the algorithm should be, tha's what i asked... The main principle is that the added value is obviouly not change, and all the other value reduce to match the total of 100...

Comment: Hey @RoyBarOn I'm curious whether my answer would have worked for you, any chance you could spare the time to check it out at some point?

Comment: @BenStephens, thanks, unfortunately it did not, you can review kinglish solution to have better understanding of what i needed or what was the problem with your solution - any how - thanks for you time !

Comment: I've noticed that for the supplied example with a result of [40,40,20,0] kinglish's solution gives [40,41,19,0] so I'm not sure reviewing it will enlighten me that much about what my answer should be doing differently. Anyway, happy coding. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach uses 2 `reduce()` cycles, one to set the new values, and the next to shave or add the tiny bit left over. I have put in a half-dozen tests below, they all add up.

```js
function calcSkills(curV, nV, nvI) {
  console.log("---------------\nrunning calcSkills")
  console.log("curV", curV.join(","));
  console.log('newValue', nV, 'at index', nvI)
  curV[nvI] = nV
 let cValues = curV.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
  if (cValues < 100) { outArr = curV }
  else {
  console.log(typeof curV)
    let newOrder = [...curV]
    newOrder.sort((a, b) => a - b)

    let orderMap = newOrder.reduce((b, a) => {
      let tmp = curV.indexOf(a);
      let ct = 0;
      while (b.indexOf(tmp, ct) !== -1) {
        tmp = curV.indexOf(a, tmp + 1)
        ct++
      }
      b.push(tmp);
      return b
    }, [])

    let uvalueIndex = newOrder.indexOf(curV[nvI])
    curV = newOrder, nvI = uvalueIndex, outArr = [], diff = cValues - 100, ttl = 0, nonz = 0;

    let nvals = curV.reduce((b, a, i) => {
      if (nvI !== i) a = a - Math.floor(a / 100 * diff); // if not the newly added number, find out our relative percentage and subtract it from the original number
      b.push(a);
      ttl += a;
      if (a != 0 && nvI !== i) nonz++;
      return b
    }, []);
    let overage = (ttl % 100),
      ldiff = Math.ceil(overage / nonz) * (ttl > 100 ? -1 : 1); // ldiff determines how to spread the overage/underage so we get to 100
    let numspots = Math.ceil(Math.abs(ldiff) / nonz)
    nvals = nvals.reduce((b, a, i) => {
      if (a !== 0 && nvI !== i && numspots > 0) {
        let fval = a + ldiff
        if (fval < 0) ldiff += Math.abs(fval)
        a += ldiff;
        overage += ldiff
        nonz--;
        if (nonz < 1)  a -= overage
      }
      b.push(a);
      return b;
    }, [])

    // reassemble
    //console.log(nvals.join(","), orderMap.join(","))
    orderMap.forEach((o, i) => outArr[o] = nvals[i])
  }
  console.log('Result:', outArr.join(","));
  return outArr
}

/*-------- Testing ----------*/

arrToCalc = [0, 0, 67, 33]
nvI = 1
newVal = 75
calcSkills(arrToCalc, newVal, nvI)

arrToCalc = [3, 13, 44, 1]
nvI = 1
newVal = 74
calcSkills(arrToCalc, newVal, nvI)


arrToCalc = [1, 20, 61, 18]
nvI = 2
newVal = 76
calcSkills(arrToCalc, newVal, nvI)


arrToCalc = [0, 50, 25, 0]
nvI = 0
newVal = 40
calcSkills(arrToCalc, newVal, nvI)

/*
arrToCalc = [0, 60, 25, 0]
nvI = 3
newVal = 40
calcSkills(arrToCalc, newVal, nvI)

arrToCalc = [50, 40, 10, 0]
nvI = 3
newVal = 40
calcSkills(arrToCalc, newVal, nvI)

arrToCalc = [80, 10, 10, 0]
nvI = 3
newVal = 60
calcSkills(arrToCalc, newVal, nvI)
*/
```

Comment: Thanks - but the changed value should remains the same - and all the rest should reduce by their values in compering to the new value - so for example - this my current state [0,50,25,0] - and i've changed index 0 to 40 - so the result will be [40, 40, 20,0] ,

Comment: I'm confused - those are exactly the results this is getting. Are you seeing something different in the half-dozen tests I run in the snippet?

Comment: Thanks, i've run into some bugs with your answer that i can't reproduce, in some case i get negative values... so - i'm checking it and let you know soon

Comment: ok, shoot over some parameters that give you incorrect results and I'll take a look

Comment: I did notice that if the initial values array added up to more than 100, everything was wrong in the result. However, I didn't think that could happen in your code, so I didn't try and figure it out.

Comment: try  arrToCalc = [1, 20, 61, 18]
 newValueIndex = 2
 newVal = 76 - the Result: -3,11,76,16 - had a negative value

Comment: Sorry - still having negative values [44, 13, 3, 1], 74,  1  - returns -5,30,74,1 - i'm trying to debug it myself - look like the problem is in the second reducer

Comment: sorry, I forgot about the last val affected, just a moment

Comment: Holy moly, my head hurts. It's ready now. The trick was (many things actually) mainly to presort the array by values so it was top-heavy, thereby not running into a tiny value at the end resultting in a negative number. Taking apart and reassembling the array was a trick. I think I'll treat myself to a couple beers after this :)

Comment: (i'll probably go straight to hell after this answer ...haha ) thanks for the effort - unfortunately i'm still experiencing some problems with the values... i've updated the question with a short video - with your solution - the problem as you can see is that it's added values when the total isn't 100 ...i'll take a better look tomorrow - good night!

Comment: My bad, a couple lines were out of place. answer updated and compliant with sub-100 numbers

Comment: Thanks - did you've notice the console error?  Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'curV' before initialization ? i'm trying to handle it - but for some reason - the curV 'lost it's scope' i the first else .... never seen it ...haha... it's happen with numbers which are greater then 100 ..

Comment: try arrToCalc = [0, 0, 67, 33]
 newValueIndex = 75
 newVal = 1 - getting 5 values .. [0, 0, 0, 32, 68]

Comment: @RoyBarOn - they were both the same issue. When I minimized my code last time, I accidentaly overwrote something important, but it's fixed now. pls test

Comment: Thanks - now you nailed it.

Comment: Cheers mate! That was fun

Answer (score 0):

After calculating the total score, reduce that from 100, and store it in the variable (here extra), then run a while loop utill that value becomes 0.

In the below snippet, I am running a loop and in each iteration reducing the value by 10. You can change the reduction logic as per the requirement.

```js
function calcSkills(currentValues, newValue, newValueIndex){

  for(let i =0; i < currentValues.length; i++){
    if(i == newValueIndex){
      currentValues[i] = newValue;
    }
  }

  let calcValues = currentValues.reduce((a,b)=>{
    return a +b;
  })

  if(calcValues < 100){
    console.log('less', currentValues)
  }
  else {
    let isValidVal = false;
    let extra = calcValues - 100;
    
    while(!isValidVal) {
      for(let i=0; i<currentValues.length; i++) {
        if (i != newValueIndex && currentValues[i] > 0) {
          if (extra >= 10) {
            currentValues[i] -= 10;
            extra -= 10;
          } else {
            currentValues[i] -= extra;
            extra = 0;
          } 
        }
      }
    
      if (extra == 0) {
        isValidVal = true;
      }
    }
    console.log('greather', currentValues)
  }
}
    
 arrToCalc = [44, 55, 25, 0]
 newValueIndex = 2
 newVal = 40
 calcSkills(arrToCalc, newVal, newValueIndex)
```

Comment: Thanks - but the changed value should remains the same - and all the rest should reduce by their values in compering to the new value - so for example - this my current state [0,50,25,0] - and i've changed index 0 to 40 - so the result will be [40, 40, 20,0] ,

Comment: @RoyBarOn The same is happening over here.

Comment: Don't think so - the value that being changed (new val = 40) is going through the calculating process which he shouldn't - the main idea is that the rest of the vals will be calculate according to the new val - but not the new val - since he is the starting point.

Comment: - The player adds 25 Armor.  
  Stamina: 0 | Speed: 50 | Armor: 25 | Strength: 0 | _Remaining: 25_  
- The player now adds 40 Stamina. The excess is automatically reduced from the other skills, weighted by their current values.  
  Stamina: 40 | Speed: 40 | Armor: 20 | Strength: 0 | _Remaining: 0_

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt at the problem, I'm not sure a possible remainder is always going to land in the most desirable place, maybe that's something that could be tweaked.

```js
const distribute_remainder_for_indexes = (arr, indexes, remainder) => {
  const sorted_indexes = [...indexes].sort((a, b) => arr[b] - arr[a]);
  
  return arr.map((v, i) => {
    const ii = sorted_indexes.indexOf(i);
    return v - ((ii > -1 && ii < remainder) ? 1 : 0);
  });
};

const distribute_reduction_for_indexes = (arr, indexes, reduction) => {
  const total = indexes.reduce((acc, v) => acc + arr[v], 0);
  const reduced = arr.map((v, i) => v - (indexes.includes(i) ? Math.floor(v * reduction / total) : 0));
  
  return distribute_remainder_for_indexes(
    reduced, indexes,
    indexes.reduce((acc, v) => acc + reduced[v], 0) - (total - reduction)
  );
};

function calcSkills(current, new_value, new_index) {
  const max_value = 100;
  
  let copy = [...current];
  copy[new_index] = Math.min(new_value, max_value);
  
  const excess = copy.reduce((a, b) => a + b) - max_value;
  
  return excess > 0 ?
    distribute_reduction_for_indexes(
      copy,
      copy.reduce((a, v, i) => i !== new_index && v > 0 ? a.concat(i) : a, []),
      excess
    ) :
    copy;
}

console.log("[44, 55, 25, 0], 40, 2 ::", ...calcSkills([44, 55, 25, 0], 40, 2));
console.log("[0, 50, 25, 0], 40, 0  ::", ...calcSkills([0, 50, 25, 0], 40, 0));
console.log("[44, 13, 3, 1], 74, 1  ::", ...calcSkills([44, 13, 3, 1], 74, 1));
console.log("[80, 10, 10, 0], 60, 3 ::", ...calcSkills([80, 10, 10, 0], 60, 3));
console.log("[0, 9, 90, 1], 60, 0   ::", ...calcSkills([0, 9, 90, 1], 60, 0));
console.log("[0, 10, 50, 0], 20, 0  ::", ...calcSkills([0, 10, 50, 0], 20, 0));
console.log("[0, 10, 10, 8], 73, 0  ::", ...calcSkills([0, 10, 10, 8], 73, 0));
console.log("[0, 8, 10, 10], 73, 0  ::", ...calcSkills([0, 8, 10, 10], 73, 0));
```